# PHP & WP: is_wp_error not working on try and catch

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I posted the following question [PHP & WP: try catch not working when error from DB is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018514/php-wp-try-catch-not-working-when-error-from-db-is-thrown/58018744?noredirect=1#comment102441337_58018744). Currently I'm trying to prevent the application from crashing when the database is `--read-only`.

Currently, I get the following error:

> WordPress database error INSERT command denied to user
>   'readonly'@'10.XXX.XX.XX' for table 'responses' for query INSERT INTO
>   `responses` (`uid`, `data`) VALUES

This happens when a database that has `--read-only` access is trying to insert data into it. During a cluster fail over out writer database became the reader and therefore this issue happen. I try to write error handling for it without success.

```
function drools_request($data, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($data),
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

The variable `$db` is a database from an AWS RDS endpoint, which had `--read-only` accesss. So when `$db->insert` throws an error I expect the logs on WP engine to have shown `'Error writing to database: '` however, this didn't happen and what I saw was `WordPress database error INSERT command denied to user ...`

Why isn't the error handling working in this case? Not being able to write into the database shouldn't stop the website from working. Here is the full class.

```
<?php

namespace StatCollector;

function drools_request($data, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($data),
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function drools_response($response, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("responses", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($response),
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function results_sent($type, $to, $uid, $url = null, $message = null) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("messages", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "msg_type" => strtolower($type),
      "address" => $to,
      "url" => $url,
      "message" => $message
    ]);
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function peu_data($staff, $client, $uid) {
  try {
    if (empty($uid)) {
      return;
    }
    $db = _get_db();

    if (! empty($staff)) {
      $insertion = $db->insert("peu_staff", [
        "uid" => $uid,
        "data" => json_encode($staff)
      ]);
    }
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
    if (! empty($client)) {
      $insertion = $db->insert("peu_client", [
        "uid" => $uid,
        "data" => json_encode($client)
      ]);
    }
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion ) ) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e){
    echo 'Error writing to database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}


function response_update() {
  $uid = $_POST['GUID'];
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $programs = $_POST['programs'];
  if (empty($uid) || empty($url) || empty($programs)) {
    wp_send_json(["status" => "fail","message" => "missing values"]);
    return wp_die();
  }

  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("response_update", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "url" => $url,
      "program_codes" => $programs
    ]);
    wp_send_json(["status" => "ok"]);
    wp_die();
    if( is_wp_error( $insertion )) {
      echo $return->get_error_message();
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to database: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}

function _get_db() {
  $host = get_option('statc_host');
  $database = get_option('statc_database');
  $user = get_option('statc_user');
  $password = get_option('statc_password');
  $bootstrapped = get_option('statc_bootstrapped');

  $host = (!empty($host)) ? $host : $_ENV['STATC_HOST'];
  $database = (!empty($database)) ? $database : $_ENV['STATC_DATABASE'];
  $user = (!empty($user)) ? $user : $_ENV['STATC_USER'];
  $password = (!empty($password)) ? $password : $_ENV['STATC_PASSWORD'];
  $bootstrapped = (!empty($bootstrapped)) ? $bootstrapped : $_ENV['STATC_BOOTSTRAPPED'];

  if (empty($host) || empty($database) || empty($user) || empty($password)) {
    error_log('StatCollector is missing database connection information. Cannot log');
    return new MockDatabase();
  }

  $db = new \wpdb($user, $password, $database, $host);
  $db->show_errors();

  if ($bootstrapped !== '5') {
    __bootstrap($db);
  }
  return $db;
}
```

How can can error handling to work?

Comment: Pls do not post the same question multiple times. Edit the original question with any updates you have.

Comment: This is a completely different question. This is not regarding `try` and `catch` as posted in the first post. This is about `wp_error` not raising an error. I strongly disagree with editing the first question, the posted answers to the first post were correct but not a solution to the overall problem.

Comment: Reopened question.

Answer (score 0):

Because as [per the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) an `insert` on the `wp_db` class **does not throw an error** if it failed.

It just returns false. A `try..catch` block will catch errors that are thrown.

In this case you should just check if the result of the `insert` was `=== false`.